# Did Umar remove the jibab of slave girls or only the hijab

Tags: hadith, women, slavery

Some Hadith only mention that umar removed the slave women’s hijab       Umar saw one of our maidservants wearing a veil and he flogged her. Umar said: Do not resemble free women.

Source: Muṣannaf Ibn Abī Shaybah 6/236.

However there is a different hadith which state that slave girls could not wear the jibab (meaning that they were bear chested) Hadith for this is

Companion Anas reported: "Umar saw one of our slave girls covering herself with Muqna (which is an outer garment like Jilbab and was used to cover the breasts and body), so he struck her and said, 'Do not resemble the free women

Another one states
Umar once saw a young girl leaving the house of Hafsa (his daughter), adorned with a cloak (i.e. Jilbab) — or, from one of the houses of the Prophet’s wives. Umar entered the house and said, “Who is this girl?” They said, “A slave of ours” — or, a slave of someone’s family. He became enraged at them and said, “Your slave girls left with their adornment, and created discord (by taking Jilbab) amongst the people (while they were unable to distinguish her from the free Muslim women).”
And
Anas bin Malik said: "I entered upon Umar bin Al-Khattab with a female slave that he knew, either from the Muhajireen or the Ansar, and she was wearing a well-adorned cloak (i.e. Jilbab, which was used to cover her breasts and body with it). He asked her, 'Have you been set free?' She replied, 'No.' He then said, 'What is with the cloak?' 'Take it off your head. The cloak is only for the free women among the believers.' She hesitated, so he got up and took it off her head forcefully, hitting her with a whip until he removed it from her head.

So is it true that umar removed the slaves chest cover or did he just remove the hijab.

Comment: The Jilbab is not a chest cover. It is the outermost article of clothing which covers the entire body.